# how to import shapefile into correct Postgres geometry field type using ogr2ogr

Tags: postgresql, gis, arcgis, geo

I'm trying to import zwillow shapefiles into postgres using ogr2ogr and I see the data for the geometry coming in as a byte data type instead of a polygon or geometry.

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname=neighborhoods" ZillowNeighborhoods-NY.shp -nln neighborhoods -append
```

How can I get it to imprt the geometry info into the postgres native geometry formats?

Comment: Which kind of geometries are you importing? Try this query:  `select distinct st_geometrytype(wkb_geometry) from neighborhoods;`. If the geometries are postgis polygons, you can simple cast them to postgres polygons: `select wkb_geometry::polygon from neighborhoods;`

Answer (score 3):

The real problem is that Postgis is not enabled/installed in your database. 
ogr2ogr automatically imports geometries as Postgis native format if Postgis is installed.

If Postgis is not installed, than the geometries are imported as bytea.

So the solution is: enable Postgis in your database. Read the instructions here: http://postgis.net/install/

<s>ogr2ogr does not support this, but you can simple cast the postgis geometries in Postgres geometries. How exactly it depends which geometries are you importing. I.e you can cast Postgis polygons/multipolygons to Postgres polygons in this way:</s>

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN ST_geometrytype(wkb_geometry) = 'ST_Polygon' THEN  
wkb_geometry::polygon 
WHEN ST_geometrytype(wkb_geometry) = 'ST_MultiPolygon' THEN 
((ST_dump(wkb_geometry)).geom)::polygon  END 
FROM neighborhoods ;
```

Comment: I don't think  postgres supports the function ST_geometrytype, it's exported as a binary data type into postgres  ~ 17:25:55 Kernel error: ERROR:  function st_geometrytype(bytea) does not exist~

Comment: Well, you don't have Postgis installed in your database. I always thought ogr2ogr would fail if Postgis is not installed in the database, but you are right, if Postgis is not installed, the geometries are imported as bytea. You have to install Postgis, than you can use ogr2ogr, shp2pgsql and all other gis tools to manage geometries in Postgres. Otherwise I don't know tools which convert shape files in Postgres native geometry types. Which OS are you using? Installing Postgis in the most OS is pretty easy. What do say the command `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` in the psql console?